# Can I take tax deductions for a second residence where my son lives?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, tax-deduction, irs

I own a small second residence where my disabled son lives. He is unable to pay any rent and probably never will. For income tax purposes, can I depreciate the house, deduct property taxes and anything else? I also pay for all utilities; are these deductible?

Comment: Are you claiming your son as a dependent on your tax return?

Comment: yes I am claiming my son as a dependent

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This would be considered your secondary residence and you can deduct mortgage expense and property taxes.   Since you don't draw income from the property, it would not be advisable to treat it as investment property where you can deduct other maintenance expenses and depreciate the house.